# Allowing Remote Access to a MySQL Server (Windows | PyMySQL)

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, server, mysql-workbench, pymysql

I am creating a python tkinter application that will run on different computers all on one wifi network. Those computers should, through the tkinter app, communicate simultaneously with a database server hosted by a windows computer. I have chosen MySQL and PyMySQL to accomplish these tasks. I have experience with tkinter, but MySQL and networking in general are largely foreign to me.

I have downloaded and configured all the relevant MySQL software (Server, Router, Workbench, etc.) and created a database called `comptool` with a single table `competitors`. The server runs on `localhost` and port 3306. From the host computer, the tkinter app can interact with the database fine. From any other computer, I receive the following error when attempting to connect:

```
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it)")
```

With some searching I found many answers describing a `MySQLInstanceConfig.exe` file or a `bind-address` value in a `my.cnf` file. The `MySQLInstanceConfig.exe` file does not appear to exist in MySQL 8.0, I have been unable to find a `my.cnf` file anywhere in Windows (I suspect this might be a Linux exclusive).

There are also many mentions of specific privilege granting to the relevant database user, but all my attempts at privilege granting through the MySQL command line have returned syntax errors. I use the following line (and variations of it):

```
GRANT ALL ON comptool.* TO 'testuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';
```

But I always receive the same error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IDENTIFIED BY 'pass'' at line 1
```

Apart from any direct help, I am also curious as to why the hell there isn't simply a checkbox I can click in Workbench that allows remote access.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database_name.* TO 'testuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';
```

Then

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I received the same syntax error as before.

Comment: Which version are you using

Comment: MySQL 8.0 on Windows 10.

Comment: Please refer https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-mysql-connections-navigator-management-users-and-privileges.html